# How to sort IPv4 and IPv6 addresses together in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ip-address

Here is my dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"group": "a", "ip_address": "10.3.110.12"},  # IPV4
        {"group": None, "ip_address": "10.3.110.127"},  # IPV4
        {"group": "c", "ip_address": "2607:f140:d000:135::7e9c"},  # IPV6
        {"group": "b", "ip_address": "10.3.110.90"},  # IPV4
    ]
)
```

I want to sort Ipv4 and Ipv6 IP-addresses together in one dataframe column as ascending order.

I tried two approaches and failed to accomplish.

#### Approach 1 - convert df ip_address column values to python ip_address object and try to sort

It's working fine for one type of Ip-address either ip4 or ip6, but not together.

```py
import ipaddress

# Converting the  ip_address string value to ip_address object
df['ip_add'] = df['ip_address'].apply(lambda x: ipaddress.ip_address(x))
    
# sort df in asc and desc
df = df.sort_values(by=['ip_add'], ascending=True) # asc and desc
         
df = df.drop(["ip_add"], axis=1)
```

[image: Approach_1_error]

#### Approach 2- convert df ip_address column values to socket.inet_aton values and sort using argsort

It's working fine for one type of Ip-address i.e ip4, but not with ip6 alone as well.

```py
df = df.iloc[np.argsort(list(map(socket.inet_aton, df['ip_address'])))]
```

[image: Approach_2_error]

#### Expected result

Dataframe sorted in ascending order (smallest unit come first, i.e. Ivp4 first then Ipv6 values)

[image: result_dataframe]

Comment: And what should be the expected output? Can you edit your question and put the dataframe and expected output as text?

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks for pointing out. Added expected df in problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with your first approach, using Python standard library's [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module and [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in function, and Pandas [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```py
# Convert the  ip_address string value to ip_address object
df["ip_address"] = df["ip_address"].apply(lambda x: ipaddress.ip_address(x))

# Split dataframe between IPv4 and IPv6 values, sort separately 
# and concatenate them back together
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[df["ip_address"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, ip_add))].sort_values(
            by="ip_address"
        )
        for ip_add in (ipaddress.IPv4Address, ipaddress.IPv6Address)
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
```

[image]